# What is the purpose of the DAMSM loss for the generators in AttnGAN?

Tags: objective-functions, papers, generative-adversarial-networks, attn-gan

I am confused about the training part in [AttnGan](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Xu_AttnGAN_Fine-Grained_Text_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf).

If you observe page 3. There are two types of losses for generator network: one involving the *Deep Attentional
Multimodal Similarity Model (DAMSM)* loss $(L_{DAMSM})$ and the others for individual generator $(L_{G_i})$ for $i= 1, 2, 3$.

My doubt is: if each generator has its own loss function that is useful in training, what is the purpose in using $L_G$, i.e., with DAMSM loss function? Is my assumption wrong?